# Cross-Platform API to monitor file system in C?

Tags: c, filesystems, cross-platform, watch

I'm looking for a cross platform library to detect when files in a directory are added or modified.
I know there are OS specific way to do this (inotify for Linux, FindFirstChangeNotification for windows, etc...).

But is there a platform independent library that works specifically in **C**? (Like the QFileSystemWatcher in C++)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now 2021 so maybe [septag/dmon](https://github.com/septag/dmon) is your cup of tea.

From the description:

> Single header C99 portable library for monitoring directory changes

... or maybe the more beefy [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch) ?

Answer (score 1):

inotify is Linux specific, if you want some UNIX portable features you are pobably looking for something like `libfam`. it is name of library. Full package name is fileschanged.

fileschanged is a GNU/Linux command-line utility that reports when files have been altered.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that library. But what I'm searching specifically is, something that will work for Windows and for Linux

Comment: The APIs are totally different for Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, and any other Unix you can name, it seems. I don't know of any cross-platform library that handles this in a consistent way.

Answer (score -6):

Sounds like a good use case for golang.
Simply change $GOOS and/or $GOARCH and run `go build`.

Boom - trivial cross-platform development.

Comment: The question asks about C, not GO.

Comment: And if using C is an arbitrarily self-imposed constraint, Go is a reasonable consideration.